# jQuery: change opacity on hover on nearby element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hover, opacity

I need to change the opacity of a image when I hover either the image or the `<p>` above it. This is the html structure

```
<div id="article-menu">
  <ul>
     <p>Image</p>
     <li><img src="..." /></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$("#article-menu img, #article-menu p").hover(function() {
    $(this).closest('img').css('opacity', 1);
}, function() {
    $(this).closest('img').css('opacity', 0.7);
});
```

This does not work. It does only work if you hover the actual image not the p element.

Comment: Can you give the `img` an ID and target that element by ID in the event handlers?

Comment: Why don't you just bind the `hover` event to `ul` tag?

Comment: Your markup is invalid. A `<p>` can't be a child of `<ul>`

Answer (score 3):

CSS only solution:

```css
#article-menu li > img {
    opacity: .7;
}

#article-menu p:hover + li > img, 
#article-menu li > img:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

...though your markup is invalid. Your `p` needs to be a `li`.

***DEMO:*** http://jsfiddle.net/DYWKU/ *(I changed the `p` to an `<li class="p">`)*

Comment: I love your simple, elegant answers, @squint. :) +1

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like -

```
$(".article-menu").hover(function(){
   $(this).find('img').css('opacity', 1);
}, function(){
   $(this).find('img').css('opacity', 0.7);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can maybe try with index

```
$("#article-menu img, #article-menu p").hover(function(){
    var index = $(this).index();
    var indexUp -= index;
    var indexDown += index;
    $("#article-menu img:eq("+indexUp+")").css('opacity', 1);
    $("#article-menu img:eq("+indexDown+")").css('opacity', 1);
}, function(){
    var index = $(this).index();
    var indexUp -= index;
    var indexDown += index;
    $("#article-menu img:eq("+indexUp+")").css('opacity', 0.7);
    $("#article-menu img:eq("+indexDown+")").css('opacity', 0.7);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It´s easy and only css:

Give the element a class,

```
.image:hover{moz-opacity: 0,7;}
```

Should work how you want it...didn´t test this, but this should be the way without jquery

edit: was to slow: See squint´s post-It´s much better than mine